# boost asio open more that one socket

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I am beginner in boost::asio. I have client and server that use `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket`. When I use one socket everything works fine.
But now I need to create another one. It works sometimes, but usually I get an exception during second socket `connect`.

Here is simplified code on client side:

```
boost::asio::io_service ios;
std::cout << "Connecting 1950\n";
mp_SocketReader = new SerializationSocket(host, "1950", ios);
std::cout << "Connecting 1960\n";
mp_SocketWriter = new SerializationSocket(host, "1960", ios);
```

on server side:

```
boost::asio::io_service ios;
SerializationSocket socketReader(1950, ios);
SerializationSocket socketWriter(1960, ios);
```

And part of `SerializationSocket` code:

```
class SerializationSocket {
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket *mp_Socket;

public:
    /* As client */
    SerializationSocket(std::string host, std::string port, boost::asio::io_service& ios) {
        mp_Socket = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(ios);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(ios);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(host, port);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
        std::cout << "Before connect\n";
        connect(*mp_Socket, iterator);
        std::cout << "After connect\n";
    }

    /* As server */
    SerializationSocket(int port, boost::asio::io_service& ios) {
        mp_Socket = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(ios);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(ios, endpoint);
        acceptor.accept(*mp_Socket);
    }
};
```

Output when issue occurs (on client side):

```
Connecting 1950
Before connect
After connect
Connecting 1960
Before connect
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >'
  what():  connect: Connection refused
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What can be reason for such behavior?

update: Little `sleep()` between socket connection help to avoid issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use blocking sockets. This means your server doesn't start listening on port 1960 until client connects to port 1950. Now you have a race condition, sometimes client is faster than server and tries to connect when server is not listening yet.

Possible solutions:

1. use async (non-blocking) sockets, at least on server side, so you
   can start listening/accepting on both of them.
2. blocking sockets but accept connections on two threads
3. create acceptor in server socket constructor but move call to `accept` to another method, now create two server sockets and then call `accept` on both of them. I'm not sure about this, don't remember how **Asio** is implemented but worth to try as this would be the simplest solution.